# Using Custom Attached Properties with Base Class and Generics

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, base-class, attached-properties

I wish to use AngelSix's custom attached properties [Code](https://www.csharpcodi.com/vs2/306/fasetto-word/Source/Fasetto.Word/AttachedProperties/BaseAttachedProperty.cs/#) in a .NET Framework 4.7.2 class library. However, when I try to add an attached property to an object in a Xaml file, what I get from Intellisense in Visual Studio is `` local:BaseAttachedProperty`2.value `` and not the desired attached property like `local:IsBusyProperty.Value`.  When I manually type `local:IsBusyProperty.Value`, the application crashes with the error message `The method or operation is not implemented` pointing to the attached property.
I understand that the  `` `2 `` means a generic type, with 2 generic parameters - alluding to the Base Class with two generic parameters:

```
public abstract class BaseAttachedProperty<Parent, Property>
        where Parent : new(){}
```

But how do I get the correct attached property, that is, classes that implement the base class with generic parameters and not this cryptic `` local:BaseAttachedProperty`2.value `` message?

If I create an Attached Property without inheriting from the BaseAttachedProperty, everything works fine.

A user on a [German Forum](https://mycsharp.de/forum/threads/122459/attached-propertiesmithilfe-generischer-basisklasse-in-einer-zeile-erzeugen) had the same problem and writes that he could use `xmlns:` to get the attached properties but this does not work for me!

Here is a sample that AngelSix provided. It will not work for me.

```
public class IsBusyProperty : BaseAttachedProperty<IsBusyProperty, bool>
{
}
```

Here is my code which works:

```
public class IsBusyProperty
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Value", typeof(bool), typeof(IsBusyProperty), new PropertyMetadata(false));
        public static bool GetValue(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(ValueProperty);
        }
        public static void SetValue(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

The code is consumed as follows (here my code is not in use):

```
<Button Content="Login" 
                                    IsDefault="True"
                                    local:BaseAttachedProperty`2.Value="{Binding LoginIsRunning}" <-- Here is the trouble area
                                    Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Page}" 
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
```

If the attached property works, the correct code should be

```
<Button Content="Login" 
                                    IsDefault="True"
                                    local:IsBusyProperty.Value="{Binding LoginIsRunning}"
                                    Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Page}" 
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
```

Comment: Please include your C# code where you make use of `BaseAttachedProperty`

Comment: @KeithStein I have updated the question with more details

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the code you linked to, but from what I see I think you're misunderstanding how it's meant to be used. Let me bring your attention back to this code you referenced:

```
public class IsBusyProperty : BaseAttachedProperty<IsBusyProperty, bool>
{
}
```

That is not an exmaple you're supposed to fill in, that is actually a fully functional attached property that you can use. The reason it's empty is because all the code you need is already in the base class `BaseAttachedProperty`.

You *do* need to import the proper `xmlns` (XML namespace) to use it, which would be the namespace where the `IsBusyProperty` class is defined. If you want to use the one already defined in the Fasetto.Word library, the code would probably be:

```
xmlns:fas="clr-namespace:Fasetto.Word;assembly=Fasetto.Word"

...

<Button fas:IsBusyProperty.Value="{Binding LoginIsRunning}"/>
```

I'm not 100% sure if the `assembly=Fasetto.Word` part is correct, but Visual Studio should tell you what the correct value is if you start typing `xmlns:fas="clr-namespace:Fasetto.Word`. `fas` is just an abritrary name I picked from the first 3 letters of the the library name, but you can use anything as long as you're consitant. For more info on `xmlns`, check out the [MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/xaml-namespaces-and-namespace-mapping-for-wpf-xaml).

---

If you want to create your own attached property using `BaseAttachedProperty`, you would do something like this:

```
public class SomeOtherProperty : BaseAttachedProperty<SomeOtherProperty, TypeOfProperty>
{
}
```

And then you would use it like this:

```
<Button yourns:SomeOtherProperty.Value="{Binding Something}"/>
```

Where `yourns` is the `xmlns` for whatever namespace you defined `SomeOtherProperty` in.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your reply. I have very well understood what you have written. As a matter of fact, I have done exactly that. That is to say, the BaseAttachedProperty is in my local namespace and I have created a class which inherits from the BaseAttachedProperty. In my xaml page, I have included the local namespace xmlns:local="clr-namespace:My.Assembly; But intellisense does not show. I tried creating an own AP without the BaseAttachedProperty class - intellisense shows my own AP and I can use it in xaml.

Comment: I am wondering if I need to change the  `ownerType : typeof(BaseAttachedProperty<Parent, Property>)` to something different for the `APs` to be visible in XAML.

Comment: @Dorogzz Huh, I gave it a test myself and I do see the same thing, IntelliSense does only suggest ``BaseAttachedProperty`2``. You can still use the property as intended if you manually type `yourns:SomeOtherProperty.Value`, but it doesn't show in IntelliSense. That is annoying and strange, but I'm not sure I can help you with that part.